# Need help getting artifact names out of Jenkins for email

Tags: jenkins

I have three Jenkins projects (Maven jobs, to be exact) that have many available parameters. I've set up a way to automate running these weekly with a set of parameters using the Build Flow plugin so that I end up running a total of 12 builds. I also have a follow-up project that exists only to send an email containing some information about the builds that ran, including a link to all 12 of the artifacts.

My problem is figuring out a way to get the artifact names from all 12 jobs. I *think* the best way to do that is using the REST API, but I could use some help with that.

I am using the Editable Email Notification plugin, and I have access to the job name and build number. I probably just need a script to grab the artifact name from each job.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried the exact case you want, but you should be able to use the [depth and tree parameters of the REST API](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/05/taming-jenkins-json-api-with-depth-and.html) to narrow down the data you need.  Start with the API URL for one of the builds, which will be of the form

```
http://jenkins/job/jobname/buildnumber/api/json
```

Comment: The depth and tree parameters blog post was a fantastic link for me. Using it, I was able to construct the following URL: `https://jenkins/job/projectname/buildnumber/api/json?depth=2&pretty=true&tree=artifacts[fileName]` which will probably get me where I need to be. Thank you.